# UglifyJS - Remove specific functions calls

Tags: uglifyjs, gulp-uglify, uglifyjs2

Is there a way to discard calls to specific functions calls using Uglify2?
Like the option **drop_console** will discard calls to console.* functions. I need to discard calls to specific functions. 
For example:

```
var myObj = {
    func1: function() {},
    func2: function() {},
    func3: function() {},
};
```

Then, remove all **myObj.*** calls. Is this possible?